# ¿Cómo llamar un Fragment desde un botón en el MainActivity.java?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estoy intentando hacer un Login, y si el usuario y la contraseña son correctos, llamar un fragment que es la siguiente pantalla a la que el usuario podrá acceder.
El problema es que no se cómo llamar el fragment desde el el MainActivity.java, he investigado mucho y lo que he podido intentar es llamar el método `onCreateView()`  que está en mi clase Fragmento.java pero no sé cuales son los parámetros que le debo pasar al método.

Esta es mi clase Fragment.java

```
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

        return vista;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Este es la parte del MainActivity.java que llama al método `onCreateView()`

```
if(email.equals(Euser1)  || email.equals(Euser2) && password.equals(Password)){
           messageOK.show();
           ScreenSlidePageFragment frag = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
           frag.onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState);
       }else {
           messageF.show();
       }
```

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola un fragment representa un comportamiento o parte de una interfaz de usuario en una activity. Ofrece la posibilidad de combinar varios fragments en una sola activity y reutilizarlos en varias. Un fragment siempre estará integrado en una o varias activities (no puede ir separado)

Lo que te recomiendo es en el MainActivity crear un FrameLayout

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el MainActivity llamar a ese FrameLayout y en ese framelayout llamar a dos fragments 1) Fragment de logueo y 2) Fragment de exito de logueo.

```
LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentLogin, loginFragment).commit();
```

Y en el primer fragment que es el fragment de Login poner el usuario, el password y boton para login.

No debes usar el `onCreateView()` debes usar el metodo `onViewCreated()` y llamar a esos `EditText` y `Button` y si es que los valores son correctos entonces reemplazar el fragmento por el de logueo correcto.

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText etUsuario, etPassword;
    Button btnLogin;
    private MainActivity myContext;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        myContext = (MainActivity) context;
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    public LoginFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        etUsuario = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.usuario);
        etPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(etUsuario.getText().toString().equals("admin") && etPassword.getText().toString().equals("123")){
                    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
                    fragmentManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentLogin, homeFragment).commit();
                }else {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Intente otra vez 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    }

}
```

He creado un GitHub que funciona el codigo correlo en Android Studio espero que te sirva: https://github.com/Miguel546/mainactivityfragments

Te dejo un gif de la aplicacion que he hecho

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Luis Miguel Casas , ahora si me ha quedado todo claro y me ha funcionado 

Comment: De nada. ¡Que bueno que mi solución te haya servido [May 395](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/173056/may-395)!